# How to load a ResourceDictionary from a strong names assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have project that references 2 dlls.  if the referenced dlls are not strong named  the resources load fine and my user controls work.  The problem is I had to strong name the referenced DLLs and now my user controls give me a XamlParseException System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder with an inner of "Could not load file or assembly".  I'm guessing the static resource in the app.xaml could not be found or loaded so it thinks the assembly is not loaded.  Is there a way around this?

App.Xaml...

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Grey.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Red.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

App.xaml.cs...

```
 public partial class App
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // referenced to MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf
        MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost d = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost();
        var b = d.IsOpen;

        base.OnStartup(e);
        var app = new MainWindow();
        var context = new MainWindowVM();
        app.DataContext = context;
        app.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work fine. Can you please show how you reference the ResourceDictionary?

Comment: edited OP...  could it be the project is .Net 4.6.1?

Comment: Could you try to instantiate any type defined in the referenced assemblies in the app startup code? Does this work?

Comment: edited OP added App.xaml.cs... if that is sufficient, then yes it works.

Comment: interesting...  If I take out the user controls from the mainwindow.xaml the window loads fine and I see the referenced xaml resources.  So it's seems only the controls are having the issue.

Comment: Are the user controls define in the same App assembly? If not, maybe they still reference the old DLLs (without strong name)

Comment: >>Are the user controls define in the same App assembly?<<  Yes.   Found out that it's only the textbox element and setting a particular style on a togglebutton. I have the source but not sure what to look for.

Comment: Maybe you could enable fusion logging and get a hint from these log files?

Comment: got it working... good thing for fusion log, revision off by 2 numbers, guess it liked the xaml until it ran into something it really needed, so it faked me out. Sorry for bothering ya and thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it works; turned my comment to an answer so that it can be easier found by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable fusion logging and get a hint from this log file. 
[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

pack://application:,,,/**MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf**;component - Is "MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf" the name of your assembly? or the namespace?

Can you try using your assembly (dll) name for reference? Check out 
[Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf)  for more details..